# Missing "AddToCart, Purchase, ViewContent" events in (Facebook Pixel)?

Tags: facebook

I was trying to create Facebook dynamic Add. After running the add it's activated but 1 error showing. Missing "AddToCart, Purchase, ViewContent" events in (Facebook Pixel Name) like this

[image]

pixel code also running well

[image]

I am not understanding the error. How can i solve this? any suggestion

Thanks